# How do add a dynamic parameter in Terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I create some AWS resources in Terraform in a loop by utilising the **count** feature.

However, I have come accross a scenario I can't seem to find an answer for:

Have a look at my sample code to demonstrate this:

JSON file I inject to be used for the count. This is the var.services in the Terraform code:

```
[
    {
        "service-name"   : "frontendapp",
        "daemon"         : false
    },
    {
        "service-name"   : "backendapp",
        "daemon"         : true
    }
]
```

The Terraform code:

```
resource "aws_ecs_service" "services" {
  count           = length(var.services)
  name            = "${var.services[count.index].service-name}"
  cluster         = aws_ecs_cluster.my-ecs-cluster.id
  task_definition = aws_ecs_task_definition.my-task-definition.arn
  desired_count   = 1
  deployment_minimum_healthy_percent = 100
  scheduling_strategy =  var.services[count.index].daemon == true ? "DAEMON" : "REPLICA"
}
```

What I need:

Much like the **scheduling_strategy** in the Terraform code, I need to have a condition for the **desired_count** but instead of giving it a value, I need to omit this line entirely when `var.services[count.index].daemon == true`

I read somewhere that giving it the value of **null** would do it but that's not the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`null`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/types#null) as the other value, that is identical to omitting the line:

```
desired_count = var.services[count.index].daemon ? 1 : null
```

> a value that represents absence or omission. If you set an argument of a resource to null, Terraform behaves as though you had completely omitted it — it will use the argument's default value if it has one, or raise an error if the argument is mandatory. null is most useful in conditional expressions, so you can dynamically omit an argument if a condition isn't met.

Comment: Hmm - my last line says that too. I gave it a go but it was not behaving as expected. I will give it another go and edit the questions if needed. Thx

Comment: @Sean it *should* certainly work, maybe show your statement and what goes wrong specifically.

Comment: It's a strange one. I get both my services flagged for change.

From: desired_count  = 1
To: desired_count  = null

My line of code is exactly as yours stated above.

Any ideas?

Comment: @Sean not sure what state you currently have and what you would want to have. If you previously deployed it with a 1 and now changed the line to the conditionaly obviously it will be a change.

Comment: That much is understood but the behaviour is not expected.

Previously frontendapp was 1. Now it will be 1 for frontendapp and null for backendapp (see my JSON). However, it's flagging them both for null.

Comment: I have accepted your answer as that's what I came here for. What I am facing right now is not related to this. Thanks for your help. Quite a neat feature I didn't know about